# i am passing the path of file in request body of post call using excel file.can someone help here

Tags: rest, rest-assured

getting exception  "java.lang.IllegalStateException", "message" : "Current request is not of type [org.springframework.web.multipart.MultipartHttpServletRequest]: org.apache.catalina.connector.RequestFacade@78313fe0"

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow. Please add a code snippet which can give an idea of what you are trying to do and under what conditions you are getting this error.

Comment: Can you share the snipped code for better understanding.